# Get the list of name column values which are not common in both the tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

recently i gave an interview where the question was 
suppose there are two tables in database.
Table T1 has a column named "name" in it and few other columns
Table T2 also has a column name "name" and few other columns

suppose table T1 has values in name column as
[n1,n2,n3,n4,n5]
and values in the "name" column of table T2 are
[n2,n4]
then output should be
[n1,n3,n5] as n2 and n4 are common in both tables

we needs to find the list of names which are not common in both the tables.

The solution that i provided him was using join in the below form

```
select name from table1 where name not in (select t1.name from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.name=t2.name)
UNION
select name from table2 where name not in (select t1.name from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.name=t2.name)
```

But he said there is still a better solution. I was not able to come up with any different and more efficient solution. What is the other efficient way to get the list of names if there is any?

Comment: Information_schema.columns view where SQL standard defined to store metadata... Otherwise all_tab_columns view if information_schema database is non existing.

Comment: Are you trying to determine which **column names** are not common to both tables, or are you trying to determine which **values stored in column `name`** are not common to both tables? The title of your question appears to be at odds with the text of the question. Thanks.

Comment: @bobJarvis i have edited the title now

Answer (score 3):

If the NAME column does not have NULL values, there is also

```
select distinct(coalesce(a.name, b.name)) name
from table1 a
full join table1 b on a.name = b.name
where a.name is null or b.name is null
```

(Corrected WHERE condition, sorry...)

Comment: can you give explanation of you solution?

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

Use FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(COALESCE(t1.NAME, t2.NAME)) AS NAME
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t2.NAME = t1.NAME
  WHERE t1.NAME IS NULL OR
        t2.NAME IS NULL
```

A FULL OUTER JOIN is similar to a LEFT OUTER JOIN unioned with a RIGHT OUTER JOIN - it returns rows where data exists in the first table but not the second, or where it data exists in the second table but not the first. You could get the same effect by using

```
SELECT t1.NAME
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t2.NAME = t1.NAME
  WHERE t2.NAME IS NULL
UNION
SELECT t2.NAME
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t2.NAME = t1.NAME
  WHERE t1.NAME IS NULL
```

and in fact the above is what you'd need to do if you were using a database which doesn't support the FULL OUTER JOIN syntax (e.g. MySQL, the last time I looked).

[See this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=13a10295d2e9b5fa94839351f03a3a0f)

Answer (score 0):

Union the tables and return the values that don't have a count of 2:

```
create table t1 (
  c1 int
);
create table t2 (
  c1 int
);

insert into t1 values ( 1 );
insert into t1 values ( 3 );

insert into t2 values ( 2 );
insert into t2 values ( 3 );

commit;

select c1 only_in_one_table 
from   (
  select 'T1' t, c1 from t1
  union 
  select 'T2' t, c1 from t2
)
group  by c1
having count(*) <> 2;

ONLY_IN_ONE_TABLE   
                   1 
                   2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of `not in` with subqueries, because it behaves unexpectedly with `null` values.  And the person asking would have to explain what "better" means.  Your version is actually reasonable.

I might be inclined to approach this using aggregation:

```
select name
from ((select distinct name, 1 as in_table1, 0 as in_table2
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select distinct name, 0 as in_table1, 0\1 as in_table2
       from table2
      )
     ) t
group by name
having max(in_table1) <> max(in_table2);
```

In a real world case, you would probably have a separate table with all names.  If so:

```
select n.*
from names n
where (not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.name = n.name) and
       exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.name = n.name
      ) or
      (exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.name = n.name) and
       not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.name = n.name
      );
```

This is usually the fastest approach because it does not involve any aggregation or duplicate removal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SET operator then find the solution as below:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(NAME VARCHAR2(100));
CREATE TABLE TABLE2(NAME VARCHAR2(100));
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('A');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('B');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('C');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES('A');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES('B');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES('D');


SELECT
    NAME
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            NAME
        FROM
            TABLE1
        UNION
        SELECT
            NAME
        FROM
            TABLE2
    )
WHERE
    NAME NOT IN (
        SELECT
            NAME
        FROM
            TABLE1
            JOIN TABLE2 USING ( NAME )
    );
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possible solution:

Find those that are in the first table but not in the second table using the `MINUS` operator (which is Oracle's implementation of the standard `EXCEPT`). Then UNION that with those that are in the second but not in the first.

```
(
  select name
  from t1
  minus 
  select name
  from t2
)  
union all
(
  select name
  from t2
  minus 
  select name
  from t1
);
```

Given this setup:

```
create table t1 
(
  name varchar(10)
);
insert into t1 values ('Arthur');
insert into t1 values ('Zaphod');

create table t2 
(
  name varchar(10)
);

insert into t2 values ('Tricia');
insert into t2 values ('Zaphod');
```

This returns:

```
NAME  
------
Arthur
Tricia
```

Answer (score 0):

select id from((select id from table1)
union all
(select id from table2)) as t1
group by id having count(id)=1

Answer (score 0):

Using the basic set operations the following query should work.

(
select name from table1
union all
select name from table2
)
minus
(
select name from table1
intersect
select name from table2
)
;

Regards
Akash